# supermodular independent product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

For which choices of two supermodular capacities, the independent 
product of them (given by the formula $w(A\times B)=\mu(A)\cdot \nu(B)$), also is supermodular ?

Even particular/concrete cases of distorted supermodular capacities for $\mu$ and $\nu$ would be of interest.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include some of the relevant definitions?

Comment: A supermodular capacity $\mu$ means a monotone set function (i.e., $A\subset B$ implies $\mu(A)\le \mu(B)$) which in addition satisfies the inequality $$\mu(A\cup B)+\mu(A\cap B)\ge \mu(A)+\mu(B).$$

Comment: A supermodular distorted capacity is a set function of the form $\mu(A)=f[m(A)]$, where $f:[0, 1]\to [0, 1]$ is non-decreasing and convex on $[0, 1]$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.